# Compare if a-z or A-Z and give output with switch JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm learning JavaScript. Very new and know basic. I'm playing with various options of JavaScript.

I'm comparing a-z (lower case) and A-Z (upper case) from user input. and giving an answer base on the input.

Normally i can do this with this long code:

```
var x = prompt("Enter Your character");
switch (x) {
    case 'a':
    case 'b':
    case 'c':
    case 'd':
    case 'e':
    case 'f':
    case 'g':
    case 'h':
    case 'i':
    case 'j':
    case 'k':
    case 'l':
    case 'm':
    case 'n':
    case 'o':
    case 'p':
    case 'q':
    case 'r':
    case 's':
    case 't':
    case 'u':
    case 'v':
    case 'w':
    case 'x':
    case 'y':
    case 'z':
        document.write("Lower case");
        break;
    case 'A':
    case 'B':
    case 'C':
    case 'D':
    case 'E':
    case 'F':
    case 'G':
    case 'H':
    case 'I':
    case 'J':
    case 'K':
    case 'L':
    case 'M':
    case 'N':
    case 'O':
    case 'P':
    case 'Q':
    case 'R':
    case 'T':
    case 'U':
    case 'V':
    case 'W':
    case 'X':
    case 'Y':
    case 'Z':
        document.write("Upper case");
        break;
    default:
        document.write("It is number");
        break;
}
```

With switch I want to achieve same output but with less code! Something like this:

```
var x = prompt("Enter Your character");
switch(x) {
    case x >= 'a'|| x <= 'z':
        document.write("Lower case");
        break;

    case x >= 'A' || x <= 'Z':
        document.write("Upper case");
        break;

    default:
        document.write("It is number");
        break;
}
```

Any Help?

**Please I want to do this with only switch function. I know i can do this with if/else function but i want to do this with switch. If its not possible with switch let me know :-)**

Comment: [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) is forbidden?

Comment: do you have to use a switch statment?

Comment: Assuming that you are learning `switch` statement, your example is perfect.

Comment: No. I can achieve this with if else but i want this to work with case. @BenGlasser

Comment: Why? There's no benefit to using `switch...case` over `if...else` except in special cases, which you don't have. It's like asking us how to use a pliers to pound a nail, when the hammer is right next to you.

Comment: ha ha. I know bro. I'm not thinking about any benefit. Since i'm only learning. I have too many curiosity! if if/else can why switch can't? @Blazemonger

Comment: As [Barmar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31057981/901048) pointed out, `switch...case` works with equality tests, not Boolean comparisons. It's a shorthand for that special case only. If you don't have that special case, you should use `if...else` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `switch` statement compares the input expression with each case statement using strict comparison.

So use `true` inside the switch clause and specify expressions that evaluate to `true` in case clause:

```js
var x = prompt("Enter Your character");
switch (true) {
  case x >= "a" && x <= "z":
    alert("Lower case");
    break;
  case x >= "A" && x <= "Z":
    alert("Upper case");
    break;
  default:
    alert("Something else");
    break;
}
```

***I personally do not recommend this. This is only for learning.***

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. Your answer is perfect! Since I'm learning. Can you please explain the "true" thing more? I want to know how this is working! thanks again.

Comment: See [switch statement on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). Basically the expression specified in `switch(...)` is compared with each expression specified in `case ...`. In the above example each `x >= ...` statement is compared with `true`. Whichever case statement that matches is executed.

Answer (score 3):

You can try it with something like this.

```
<script>
var x=prompt("Enter Your character");

if (x.test(/[a-z]/)) {
document.write("Lower case");
} else if (x.test(/[A-Z]/)) {
document.write("Upper case");
} else {
document.write("It is number");
}
</script>
```

You can see more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Answer (score 2):

You could do a simple if/else

```js
var x=prompt("Enter Your character");
if(!isNaN(x))
    console.log("It is number");
else if(x.toLowerCase()==x)
    console.log("Lower case");
else if(x.toUpperCase()==x)
    console.log("Upper case"););
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the character is in in between other characters:

```
var x=prompt("Enter Your character");
if (x >= '0' && x <= '9')
    alert("number!");
else if(x >= 'a' && x <= 'z')
    alert("lowercase!");
else if(x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z')
    alert("uppercase!");
else
    alert("not a letter!");
```

Comment: I believe OP is downvoting answers after editing his own question to exclude `if...then` solutions.

Comment: OP clearly mentioned in comments (and later in the question) that he is only interested in solutions that use switch statement,

Comment: @SalmanA OP ***clearly*** did it much after multiple people answered the question in many different ways.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter to a `case` statement is something to perform an equality comparison with, you don't put a comparison there. If you want to do a comparison, use `if`, not `switch`. Also, you should be combining the comparisons with `&&`, not `||`

```
if (x >= 'a' && x <= 'z') {
    document.write('Lower case');
} else if (x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z') {
    document.write('Upper case');
} else if (x >= '0' && x <= '9') {
    documennt.write('Number');
} else {
    document.write('Something else');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try also:

```js
var x = prompt("Enter Your character");
var find = x.match(/([a-z]*)([A-Z]*)([0-9]*)/);
var type = ["Lower case","Upper case", "It is number"];

document.write(find ? type[find.lastIndexOf(x)-1] : "Unknown char")
```